# Alternatives to get LINK tokens in Ropsten, for RNG

Tags: ropsten, randomness, chainlink, faucets, random

Sorry if this question sounds like very newbie (and maybe it is.
I'm developing a Smart Contract which needs a random number generation, and after researching some time it seems that [ChainLink VRF function](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf) is the best option now, because of the problems of RNG on chain.

To [execute VRF Smart Contract](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-a-random-number) you need to [fund the Smart Contract](https://docs.chain.link/docs/fund-your-contract), in order to get random numbers.

The problem is that I want to test with faucet LINK tokens, and [Chainlink has a website working as a faucet for Ropsten](https://ropsten.chain.link/).

When I ask to test tokens, a green message is displayed with confirmation and transaction hash.

But when I try to see the transaction in Etherscan, that **transaction does not exist**.

Is there any other option to get test LINK tokens? Or another production acceptable RNG method?

Comment: Could you try Kovan or Rinkeby? Ropsten has been having a lot of issues.

Comment: Yes sure, I tried with Kovan and worked. I wanted to use Ropsten because I deploy all my test SC there.