# Getting LINK for Ropsten network

Tags: ropsten, network, chainlink

I'm trying to get LINK for Ropsten. I'm using this faucet: https://ropsten.chain.link/ and, when I've added the new token, I've used this address `0x20fe562d797a42dcb3399062ae9546cd06f63280` (Chainlink token contract address), but I'm not getting any LINK

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong? I was able to get LINK for Kovan, but I'd like to try some tests on Ropsten instead of Kovan.

**Edit:** I'm checking this link: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/ where we can find all address for Chainlink token contracts and the point is Ropsten isn't there. There's no support for Ropsten anymore?

Comment: Same problem [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91583/alternatives-to-get-link-tokens-in-ropsten-for-rng). Another question [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91928/are-there-chainlink-contacts-nodes-for-ropsten). On Rinkeby works, tested now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ropsten is finicky, and thus the Chainlink core doesn't support it.

Chainlink is much more compatible with the Kovan network with lots of user guides. It's suggested to use Kovan testnet in place of ropsten, where you will get the link token for sure.

You can find all the latest faucets and [supported chains for Chainlink here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/#kovan).